# What the function's signature means?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, methods, func, datamember

```
#ifndef _RECT
#define _RECT

#include "Point.h"

using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
private: 
    Point _topLeft;
    Point _bottomRight;
    int _color;

public:
    Rectangle( double left, double top, double width, double height, int color );
    ~Rectangle() { --m_count; };

public:
    int getColor() const;
    Point& getTopLeftPoint();

    Point& getBottomRightPoint();
    void setColor( int color );

public:
    bool contains( const Point &p );
    void moveRect( double deltaLeft, double deltaTop );
    void scaleRect( double rectWidth, double rectHeight );


    void setBigger(int x, int y) const;

public:
    static int m_count;
};

#endif
```

I didn't understand the meaning of the signatures:

```
Point& getTopLeftPoint();
Point& getBottomRightPoint();
```

Where do they belong,Is it another class constructor or is it another way to call the variables,
 I've been trying to figure out for hours

Thanks for the help

Comment: The functions return a reference to `Point`

Comment: Identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, identifiers with a double underscore, and identifiers beginning with an underscore in global scope are reserved so using them is undefined behavior. You should change `_RECT`.

Answer (score 1):

This is elementary C++ language, so you might want to brush up your knowledge.

They are member functions (or methods, if you prefer the term) that return a reference to a `Point`. If you replace the return type `Point &` with for example `int`, the syntax should look familiar. Otheriwse, you really need to go back and learn the basics.

Comment: Thanks for the orientation I just started learning the language and for a moment I didn't understand the meaning of it